# Does R have function startswith or endswith like python?

Tags: python, r, string, startswith, ends-with

```
> startsWith('abc', 'a')
[1] TRUE
> startsWith('abc', 'c')
[1] FALSE

> endsWith('abc', 'a')
[1] FALSE  
> endsWith('abc', 'c')
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: You could use a regular expression, like `iris[grepl("^Petal",names(iris))]`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Not inbuilt like that.

Options include `grepl` and `substr`.

```
x <- 'ABCDE'
grepl('^AB', x) # starts with AB?
grepl('DE$', x) # ends with DE?
substr(x, 1, 2) == 'AB'
substr('ABCDE', nchar(x)-1, nchar(x)) == 'DE'
```

Comment: (just a note) From R 3.3.0, functions `startsWith` and `endsWith` exist.

Answer (score 139):

As [added to `base` in 3.3.0](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html), `startsWith` (and `endsWith`) are exactly this.

```
> startsWith("what", "wha")
[1] TRUE
> startsWith("what", "ha")
[1] FALSE
```

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/startsWith.html

Comment: Thanks, ijoseph, please see alexis_laz's comment under the accepted answer.

Comment: @Chen - I think it still belongs as an answer, since it's what you were originally looking for.  Comments are not set in stone.

Comment: @Chen ah, I completely missed that comment before.

Comment: It was added in 3.3.0: "New string utilities `startsWith(x, prefix)` and `endsWith(x, suffix)`." from the R changelog https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html

Comment: Updated to add certainty. Thanks for investigation, @FrankPinter .

Comment: _Related_: the tidyverse package makes this available -

str_starts('abc', 'ab' ) # TRUE

Answer (score 14):

The dplyr package's `select` statement supports `starts_with` and `ends_with`.  For example, this selects the columns of the iris data frame that start with `Petal`

```
library(dplyr)
select(iris, starts_with("Petal"))
```

`select` supports other subcommands too.  Try `?select` .

Comment: The starts_with() function is for selecting columns, **not** rows!

Comment: @Michael , This has nothing to do with selecting rows.

Answer (score 13):

The simplest way I can think of is to use the `%like%` operator:

```
library(data.table)

"foo" %like% "^f"
```

evaluates as `TRUE` - Starting with *f*

```
"foo" %like% "o$"
```

evaluates as `TRUE` - Ending with *o*

```
"bar" %like% "a"
```

evaluates as `TRUE` - Containing *a*

Answer (score 3):

This is relatively simple by using the substring function:

```
> strings = c("abc", "bcd", "def", "ghi", "xyzzd", "a")
> str_to_find = "de"
> substring(strings, 1, nchar(str_to_find)) == str_to_find
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

You cut each string to the desired length with substring. The length being the number of characters you are looking for at the beginning of each string.

Answer (score 3):

Borrowing some code from the `dplyr` package [[see this]](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/50309db8f04cbcc87e4568a4bfa1f0c718e824c9/R/select-utils.R) you could do something like this:

```
starts_with <- function(vars, match, ignore.case = TRUE) {
  if (ignore.case) match <- tolower(match)
  n <- nchar(match)

  if (ignore.case) vars <- tolower(vars)
  substr(vars, 1, n) == match
}

ends_with <- function(vars, match, ignore.case = TRUE) {
  if (ignore.case) match <- tolower(match)
  n <- nchar(match)

  if (ignore.case) vars <- tolower(vars)
  length <- nchar(vars)

  substr(vars, pmax(1, length - n + 1), length) == match
}
```