# R - Function to count the number of columns in a data frame when a prefix is entered

Tags: r, dataframe, count, multiple-columns, prefix

This is a question for school, but I have been working on it for hours and just need a point in the right direction. I am not asking for the full answer.

I was given a data frame with student grades for various assessments. I have to write a function that will result in the number of columns that either start with a given prefix or match the name entirely.

I was provided with the following framework:

```
assessmentCount <- function(df, assessmentNamePrefix)
{

}
```

I need to be able to write the code to get the exact results below when the following lines of code are executed:

```
assessmentCount(df,"hw")
# [1] 7
```

and

```
assessmentCount(df,"exam1")
# [1] 1
```

I've found that the following code, when run independently of the framework and with the [hw] written in, gives the correct number of 7:

```
my_columns <- df[, grep("^[hw]", names(df), value=TRUE)]
ncol(my_columns)
```

However, when I do the same with [exam1], I get an incorrect number of 3 because it includes columns for exam1, exam2, and exam3:

```
my_columns <- df[, grep("^[exam1]", names(df), value=TRUE)]
ncol(my_columns)
```

Even worse, when I put the code into the framework and replace the values with the variable assessmentNamePrefix, I get incorrect values of 8 for both tests.

```
assessmentCount <- function(df, assessmentNamePrefix)
{
  my_columns <- df[, grep("^[assessmentNamePrefix]", names(df), value=TRUE)]
  ncol(my_columns)  
}
```

I am very frustrated at this point and am not understanding what is going wrong. I do realize that this is a very basic question, but I'm at the beginning of a very basic R programming course. Could someone please point me in the right direction? It would be very much appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: You need to learn some regex. When you are using `[exam1]`- this will match any letter between the square brackets. You could do `grep("^exam1", c("exam1", "exam2", "exam3"))` instead. And as mentioned in the comment above- just use `sum` on `grepl`.

Comment: Thank you both. I don't know why I keep jumping over simple code and thinking it has to be more difficult. I keep wanting to break everything down into bits and then analyze the bits. Of course, the more steps, the more mistakes. I will do some re-reading re: regular expression. Thanks :)

Comment: See also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31467732/does-r-have-function-startswith-or-endswith-like-python

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thank you, I will look at that.

Comment: I also found that my textbook suggests loading the stringr library and using str_detect instead of grepl. There are always so many ways of coding. 
  `sum(str_detect(names(df), assessmentNamePrefix))`

Comment: That's unfortunate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the base `startsWith()` function, which is faster and more convenient than the regular expression `grepl("^<prefix>", x)` in this case, as specified from `?startsWith()`:

> startsWith() is equivalent to but much faster than
>
> substring(x, 1, nchar(prefix)) == prefix or also
>
> grepl("^prefix", x)

```
assessmentCount <- function(df, assessmentNamePrefix)
{
    sum(startsWith(names(df), assessmentNamePrefix))    
}
```

Comment: It is nice but for some reason I cannot access `startsWith()`. Any idea why?

Comment: Old R version :) ... after update to 3.3.1 it works.

Comment: `startsWith(x, prefix)` and `endsWith(x, suffix)` were introduced in R 3.3.0.

Answer (score 2):

Your Regex appears wrong.
I think it should be:

```
sum(grepl(paste0("^",assessmentNamePrefix),names(df)))
```