# ifelse starting with, ends with, includes

Tags: r

Is there any way to implement these conditions in ifelse statement?

```
df <-data.frame(Name = c("Tom","Mary","Tim","Chris") )

ifelse(name starting with T, "YES", "NO")
ifelse(name include i, "YES", "NO")
ifelse(name ends with s, "YES", "NO")
```

Comment: `?startsWith` `?grepl` `?endsWith` - as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31467732/does-r-have-function-startswith-or-endswith-like-python - which is practically a duplicate.

Comment: This past post didn't have ifelse example, and I couldn't figure out how to implement in ifelse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `grepl()` (see `help(grepl)` and `help(regex)`):

```
ifelse(grepl('^T', df$Name), 'YES', 'NO')
ifelse(grepl('i', df$Name), 'YES', 'NO')
ifelse(grepl('s$', df$Name), 'YES', 'NO')
```

which results in the following output (easily checkable):

```
> ifelse(grepl('^T', df$Name), 'YES', 'NO')
[1] "YES" "NO"  "YES" "NO" 
> ifelse(grepl('i', df$Name), 'YES', 'NO')
[1] "NO"  "NO"  "YES" "YES"
> ifelse(grepl('s$', df$Name), 'YES', 'NO')
[1] "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "YES"
```

#### Details

`grepl()` returns a logical vector the same length as the vector that is the function's second argument, returning `TRUE` where the regular expression of the function's first argument is present and `FALSE` for elements where the expression is not found.

In regular expressions, typically, and in R in particular, `^` matches the first character and `$` matches the last. So, `^T` is a regular expression looking for a string that begins with T while `s$` is a regular expression looking for a string that ends in s.