# R str_detect but only for cases that begin with the specified string

Tags: r, string, dplyr

```
londonofficemarch<-londonofficemarch %>% 
  filter(str_detect(BNF_CODE, "0501"))
```

is my code. However, this finds values in the BNF_CODE column that have 0501 anywhere in them. I want only terms that have 0501 at the beginning of them. Is there a capability in R to do this?

Comment: You can use `startsWith(BNF_CODE, "0501")`, possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31467732/does-r-have-function-startswith-or-endswith-like-python/38151842#38151842

Comment: Or, use the regex special character `^` which indicates the start of the string, so `str_detect(BNF_CODE, "^0501")` will also work

Comment: You can also use `str_detect(BNF_CODE, "^0501")`. The `^` matches the pattern but only at the start of a string. (EDIT: Sorry didn't see the above answer)